# Nichrome wire not heating up in circuit

Tags: power-supply

Making a hot wire foam cutter, Using 24 Swg gauge Nichrome wire.
Resistance of wire is 4.39 Ohm/M. I'm using 5cm so divided the amount of resistance as per cm respectively that would be 0.219 Ohms and did a testing with a multi meter. I'm using a 12 volt 1 amp adapter. Fitted up the whole circuit and powered it up but the Nichrome is not heating up. checked for broken circuit but everything seems to be fine. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If R = 0.219 Ohms to reach >1000'C may need > 12W ~ 15W

- Since V²/R=P  , V=√(R*P) = √(0.22Ω*15W) = 1.82V
- Since I=V/R  , I = 8.3A

Consider using AWG 30 to 36 with 5V to 12V or use an ATX power source 3.3V 20A supply with current limiting.

Industrial foam cutters prefer to use smaller gauge.

Comment: Or a low voltage transformer like this one https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/triad-magnetics/F-3X/237-1993-ND/5032206

Comment: Yes good choice for 25W  in 5cm (2")  but not sure if that would exceed  Tmax (1200'C?)  Ideally a sensing circuit that measures ESR might be able to regulate temperature with a 20 mohm FET.

Comment: Or he could test it with an an cheap SLA/car battery. But ATX seems to be a better choice as you have mentioned. Lots of power in a small box.

Comment: What if i place a resistor in the circuit to kick start the heating process ? Tony Stewart. EE since '75

Comment: @Illucifer do you know how to use Ohm's law? You are basically shorting your supply.  Try the suggestions made. lower V higher I amd measure it.!!

Comment: Thanks for all the heads up guys, figured it out. So what ever I do it all depends on the load current. Verified with the table chart and than came up with a conclusion my 24 swg wire requires 2.90 amps to reach 600 Fahrenheit of course depending on the cm of wire i use as the resistance changes. Measured my battery amps and it is giving only 0.65 amps so going to add a transistor to the circuit to amplify the amps.   Tony Stewart. EE since

Comment: 2.9A * 0.219 Ohms is only 0.6V across the wire, if your data is correct.

Answer (score 4):

At 12V your current would be 54A, so the current protection is definitely kicking in, and your voltage will not be anything close to 12V.

If your current is 1A, your heat will be 200mW, which should at least be warm.

It's possible that your power supply is deciding that the resistance is so low that there must be a short, and not delivering any power. It's also possible that your power supply can't physically output that low a voltage (at 1 amp, the voltage would be 0.219V), and again is just deciding to turn off instead.

edit: what you need is a higher current supply, or a longer wire.

As  Harry Svensson says, the resistance will increase as the temperature increases, but your power supply still needs to be able to supply the initial power required to get it to that temperature.

Comment: Are you sure it's 54 A though? It's nichrome wire, the resistance will change as it heats up. Can you properly apply ohm's law here?

Comment: Well ok yes, but the initial current required will be 54A, so the adapter will probably just shut down immediately.

Comment: So instead of a power adapter what if i use a 9v battery ?

Comment: @BeB00 I'm just messing with you. May ohm's law be with you.

Comment: @Illucifer that will definitely deliver some power, but exactly how much depends on the resistance characteristics of your wire and the current capabilities of your battery